# How to store CQRS Read Models in SQL Server Table?

Tags: sql-server, view, cqrs, denormalized

I'm looking into storing CQRS read models in SQL Server tables due to legacy system concerns (see approaches 2 & 3 of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11102774/97879)).

While I'd like to implement the read models using document database such as MongoDB, due to outside systems that can't be reworked at this time, I'm stuck with keeping everything in the rdbms for now.

Since I'm looking at storing records in a properly de-normalized way, what's the best way to actually store them when dealing with typical hierarchical data, such as the typical Customer / Order / LineItems /etc, that must all be displayed in the same view?  [EDIT: What I'm thinking is that I put the data needed to query the model in separate fields, but the full object in a "object data field" with it]

Due to my legacy systems (mostly out of my control) I'm thinking that I'll add triggers to the legacy system tables or make sproc changes to keep my read models current, but how should I actually store the data itself?

I considered simply storing them as JSON in a field, or storing them as XML, as both can easily be serialized/deserialized from a .net application, and can reasonably easily be updated by triggers from other activities in the database. (Xpath/XQuery isn't so bad when you get used to it, and from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4187412/97879) here, I found a [JSON parser for T-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/))

Is there a better approach?  If not, should I use XML or JSON?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with XML as it has a built-in support in SQL Server. In general I would avoid using any additional stuff written in T-SQL, as maintaining this can be a nightmare.